# Why my ruby #each block is not working as a one-liner

Tags: arrays, ruby, block, each

this is the block i wrote:

```
  half.each { |x| array << x count+=1 }
```

it just doesnt work like this but it works very good if i write it the "do...end" way:

```
 half.each do |x| 
    array << x 
    count+=1 
    end
```

it's not really important since i can work my whole method in the long way but i want to understand the one-liner ways of ruby. Thanks already.And if needed this is the whole method:

```
def length_even(array)
  half = array[(0...array.length/2)]
  count = 0
  half.each do |x| 
    array << x 
    count+=1 
    end 
  p array.drop(count).join
end
```

Comment: What is `half`?

Comment: half is just a variable. i wanted to name it "half"

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  What happens ?

Comment: Why not just `array += half; count = half.size`?

Comment: cuz i am a noob rubyist:P. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

What's the goal of your method?
Do you want to split your array in 2 and switch both halves?
[`Array#rotate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) does exactly that :

```
def length_even(array)
  array.rotate(array.length/2).join
end

puts length_even([0,1,2,3,4,5]) #=> "345012"
```

Now you have your one-liner ;)

## Notes

- If you use `p` at the end of your method, it will always display it before returning it. It might not always be desirable. It's still better than `puts` though, because your method would return `nil` otherwise.
- Your code modifies `array`, which you might not want to do.
- `each` returns the original array, so you could use `count = half.each{|x| array << x}.size`
- `count` is just `1+array.length/2`, so you don't need the previous code either.
- You might want to use join with a space, to see the difference between `[1,2,3]` and `[12,3]`
- Finally, `rotate` might be hard to find in the documentation. But you already know about [`drop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-drop), and `drop` mentions [`take`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-take).

So your code could become :

```
def length_even(array)
  half_size = array.length/2
  (array.drop(half_size)+array.take(half_size)).join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> `half.each { |x| array << x count+=1 }`

Your statements are not separated here. Normally, linebreak serves as a separator. But if you want to put several statements on the same line, use `;`

```
  half.each { |x| array << x; count+=1 }
```

Comment: @ReşitKörsu it doesn't if you code on the next line. Also, you can use `with_index` here maybe, save you having to define a counter yourself.

Comment: @ReşitKörsu: don't forget to accept helpful answers :)